# Calling event handler in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I have this template :

```
<template name='foo'>
<button id='hello'>Click me</button>
</template>
```

I have this Event handler

```
Template.foo.events({
'click #hello':function(){

  alert('hi');

  var clone=$('#hello').clone(true,true);
  $('#hello').replaceWith(clone);
}
});
```

Now the problem is , the alert doesn't alert anymore after replacing the original button rendered, How can I reapply the alert after replacing the original document in the dom?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Meteor to insert any DOM. Using the UI.insert logic.

First you need to make your element a separate template or ui component:

```
<template name="button">
    <button id='hello'>Click me</button>
</template>

<template name="foo">
    {{>button}}
</template>
```

Then you can remove it and replace it manually

```
$('#hello').remove();
UI.insert(UI.render("button"), [dom area of where to insert it]);
```

Where the dom area is something that indicates where you want to put it. You can use the `firstNode` value returned in the Template rendered callback (this.firstNode) to mimic the same area given by `replaceWith` in your code above.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I didn't exactly follow your solution but it really helped me.